# Using an empty class as "Control Token"

Tags: oop

I am working on a game and as idealistic as I am, I want to treat the human player exactly the same as the AI. The problem is that the player uses an AI means that it has to be asynchronous. As such I came up with a solution somewhat like this:

```
interface PlayerOrAI
{
    takeTurn();
}

class Game
{
    doMove(Move move);
}
```

The `Move` class is a class describing the move the player takes. (You can easily make a version into something without that extra class, but I thought that this was the easier representation for the question).
The idea is that the Game class calls the `takeTurn()` function of either the player or the AI, and then they think and when they are done, they make an instance of the Move class and return it through the use of the `doMove()` function.
(With this design you have to make sure that your AI also does the callback asynchronously, as otherwise you are slowly moving towards a stack overflow).

However, the problem that comes up is that I want to be able to check if the move is from the correct source. Of course, I could just rely on writing "correct" code from here on, but I would prefer to actually check this. I came up with a solution that uses a token, as below.

```
class Token
{
}

interface PlayerOrAIWithToken
{
    takeTurn(Token token);
}

class GameWithToken
{
    private Token currentToken;

    doMove(Move move, Token token);
}
```

Here, the idea is that the `GameWithToken` class will make a new `Token` before calling `takeTurn()`, storing it in `currentToken` and then passing it to the class that has the turn when calling `takeTurn()`. The `PlayerOrAI` then has to give the `Token` as an argument to `makeMove()`. This way `GameWithToken` can always validate that the Move was coming from the right player.

It seems perfect. A little too perfect, if you ask me. You can use it in just about any OOP language and you are using the systems already in place in a language to solve a problem. Yet, I have never heard of it, nor can I find any reference to it anywhere.

Am I just missing something when looking for a precedent for this? Am I perhaps making a solution to a problem I am making up? Is there something else going on that I am missing? Or is this just a very simple yet sound way to solve a problem like that?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simply implementing doMove with a "playerNumber"-argument be enough? and then just either queuing or returning a false for "it's not your turn" from doMove?

It's not entirely clear why both players have to be calling asynchronously either, since it seems to me the game is turn-based, and thus the game could just as easily loop and call a "performMove"-method on each players that does any calculations, performs a move and then returns (thus not building up to a stack overflow as you mention).

Comment: The playerNumber argument (or something like the actual player object) would work, but it does rely on the player implementation not trying to cheat. Obviously, it is not hard to write code that doesn't try to cheat, but from an idealistic point of view, it is better to write code in which your player components are unable to cheat.

Comment: As for the asynchronousness of the proposed solution, the issue is that the user interface is asynchronous, as such, your system can't be entirely synchronous. You can either go for a hybrid system that can handle both synchronous and asynchronous players/AIs or you can go with a asynchronous solution, which requires all players/AIs to be asynchronous. I went with the latter as I don't know how to build such a hybrid system.

Comment: Well, the AI wouldn't suddenly decide to spring up and cheat unless you tell it to, thus you can simply avoid that by keeping that rule unbroken. Same goes for multiple human players, just don't give them any accessible way to change their player-number. As long as you don't write any code to allow them to change their player-number, it should be a simple matter of queueing the moves, and "taking the moves" in the decided player order. If one player should decide to do 10 moves before the other can do anything, then the last 9 will wait in line, until you have a move from the correct player.

Comment: Of course I realize I could do that, and it would make my program do what is supposed to do. But I was thinking a little further about a way to make cheating impossible, perhaps allowing other people to write their own AI, so the two could compete. My point is that I always was aware of your "solution" and it doesn't add anything that you are mentioning it.

Comment: On top of that, I wasn't really asking about the game and how to do things there. I was asking about the strategy of using an empty class "like that" and to explain what "like that" is told the story of the program I was using it in.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was merely answering the "solving a problem that doesn't exist". In effect your solution uses a void* (or object-handle or whatever the term is in the language at hand) as a GUID for the token, in some languages it is possible to make such things up, and thus possible to cheat (although, not really feasible, as guessing the correct token-number would mean guessing the exact pointer-adress of the wanted token).

Beware of how you pass it though, in Java you will be fine, but the entire thing breaks quickly if you do this in a language with call-by-value.

Comment: In addition, this solution MIGHT require some additional overhead for the creation of the token (however quite small). The alternative would be using a random number though, which isn't free from overhead either. Both may end up creating similar values multiple times though (as the memory used by a token might be reused for a later token, and a random-function might give the same value two times). When I think about it, it depends on how much memory-allocation that happens between turns, if that is very little, then the Tokens are even more likely to be duplicates.

Comment: Actually, with the Token system, there can never be duplicates. The same value can be used again later but because that can only happen once there are no more references to the original Token (because of  a managed language or reference counted pointers). As such, the same token will never be handed out twice so there won't be duplicates. It all seems to fit so perfectly, which is why I felt it had to have a drawback, be more complicated than another solution or be a known technique...